# Adding months to a pandas object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, date

I have this dataframe object:

```
    Date
2018-12-14
2019-01-11
2019-01-25
2019-02-08
2019-02-22
2019-07-26
```

What I want, if it's possible, is to add for example: `3 months to the dates`, and then `3 months to the new date (original date + 3 months)` and `repeat this x times`. I am using `pd.offsets.MonthOffset` but this just adds the months one time and I need to do it more times.
I don't know if it is possible but any help would be perfect.
Thank you so much for taking your time.
The expected output is (for 1 month adding 2 times):

```
[[2019-01-14, 2019-02-11, 2019-02-25, 2019-03-08, 2019-03-22,  2019-08-26],[2019-02-14, 2019-03-11, 2019-03-25, 2019-04-08, 2019-04-22,  2019-09-26]]
```

Comment: Share your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal done Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need loop with `f-string`s for new columns names:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    df[f'Date_added_{i}_months'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(i)
print (df)
        Date Date_added_1_months Date_added_2_months Date_added_3_months
0 2018-12-14          2019-01-01          2019-02-01          2019-03-01
1 2019-01-11          2019-02-01          2019-03-01          2019-04-01
2 2019-01-25          2019-02-01          2019-03-01          2019-04-01
3 2019-02-08          2019-03-01          2019-04-01          2019-05-01
4 2019-02-22          2019-03-01          2019-04-01          2019-05-01
5 2019-07-26          2019-08-01          2019-09-01          2019-10-01
```

Or:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    df[f'Date_added_{i}_months'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthOffset(i)
print (df)
        Date Date_added_1_months Date_added_2_months Date_added_3_months
0 2018-12-14          2019-01-14          2019-02-14          2019-03-14
1 2019-01-11          2019-02-11          2019-03-11          2019-04-11
2 2019-01-25          2019-02-25          2019-03-25          2019-04-25
3 2019-02-08          2019-03-08          2019-04-08          2019-05-08
4 2019-02-22          2019-03-22          2019-04-22          2019-05-22
5 2019-07-26          2019-08-26          2019-09-26          2019-10-26
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
month_offset = [3,6,9]
for i in month_offset:
    df['Date_plus_'+i+'_months'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x+relativedelta(months=i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are [date](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html) objects, it should be pretty easy. You can just create a `timedelta` of 3 months and add it to each `date`.

Alternatively, you can convert them to date objects with `.strptime()` and then do what you are suggesting. You can convert them back to a string with `.strftime()`.

Comment: Thank you so much @NotAnAmbiTurner